# SearchBar Ionic 3 doesn't work

Tags: ionic3, angularfire2

I get my data with angulasfire2 classes:

```
participantsList: AngularFireList<any>;
participants: Observable<any[]>;
filteredParts: Observable<any[]>;
```

In the constructor

```
this.participantsList = afDatabase.list('/paticipants');
this.participants = this.participantsList.valueChanges();
```

I want to filter the data with a searchbar on the header of my page

```
if(this.searchword == "")
  this.filteredParts =  this.participants;

else {
  this.filteredParts = this.participants.filter(guest => {return guest.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchword) > -1});
}
```

But it gives me an error:

> The property 'name' doesn't exist in type 'any[]'.

I add a new participant with

```
handler: data => {
        const newParticipant = this.participantsList.push({});

        newParticipant.set({
          id: newParticipant.key,
          name: data.name,
          surname: data.surname,
          paid: false
        });
```

In my JSON file exported from firebase I have

```
{
"paticipants" : {
"-L66ZM7Vr4pOVjHrN-L7" : {
  "id" : "-L66ZM7Vr4pOVjHrN-L7",
  "name" : "Giacomo",
  "paid" : true,
  "surname" : "Tabarelli"
},
"-L66dd9_JBypdrDgE7Y4" : {
  "id" : "-L66dd9_JBypdrDgE7Y4",
  "name" : "Paola",
  "paid" : true,
  "surname" : "Sandonà"
},
"-L66dg5ONTW84onoQKp8" : {
  "id" : "-L66dg5ONTW84onoQKp8",
  "name" : "Gianni",
  "paid" : true,
  "surname" : "Turatta"
}
}
```

Can't understand how these classes work, is this the correct way to interact with firebase? Or maybe I can use other easy classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with Ionic, Its always a good option to achieve it with `pipes`. You can find any tutorials online. here i have an alternative solution

in template this `search()` function will trigger on each key press.

```
<input name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" (keyup)="search($event)">
```

in your constructor

```
this.participantsList = afDatabase.list('/paticipants');
this.participants = this.participantsList.valueChanges();
```

above code will initially load all data in template when page loads. Add the following function in your component which will filter the data on each key press

```
search(event){
    //console.log(event.target.value); 
    let term = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
    this.participants = this.participantsList.valueChanges().map(res=> res.filter(guest => guest.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())))
  }
```

And show data in your template

```
<ng-container *ngIf="participants | async; let participantsItems; else nocontent">
    <div *ngFor="let participant of participantsItems">
        {{participant | json}}
    </div>
    <p>Search Results {{participantsItems.length}}</p>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #nocontent>No Search Result...</ng-template>
```

Comment: Now I give it a try, because I tried a lot of way but all were unsuccessful.

Comment: It says "The property 'value' doensn't exists in the type 'EventTarget'".

Comment: ok type cast the result to `HTMLInputElement`. i updated in answer

Comment: Correct man! You saved me, it's a lot of day I'm trying this without success. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I understand the filter, but now how I can count the elements of an Observable<any[]>?

Comment: you can get the `index` for `*ngFor`. and index starts from `0` so `{{i+1}}` this will print the count. check updated answer

Comment: Yep, but I need to count them in the typescript file.

Comment: you need to subscribe to the `this.participants` and loop through the items to get the count, but subscription in both template and component make unexpected behavior. for what purpose you need the count in component?

Comment: Because I need only the total amount of elements (with a certain property true o false) not the index of every one.

Comment: this should work, i didn't tried by myself. please check

Comment: Now I try, could you explain me if there is a way to alphabetical order these data?